# Microbit plant moisture device has type error on line 7 constantly

Tags: python, shared-libraries, typeerror

Im currently trying to make a program that detects plant moisture and have a status of the plants water level. All the data will be displayed on an OLED screen. I apologise if this is a very dumb and simple program as I am a beginner. It says that line 7 has a type error when I flash the code on to the MicroBit. Please help! Thank you :)

P.S ssd1306 is the OLED library

```
from ssd1306 import initialize, clear_oled
from ssd1306_text import add_text
from microbit import *
initialize()
clear_oled()
OLEDcounter = 0

def update_oled_status():
    global moisture
    moisture = pin1.read_analog()
if OLEDcounter == 0:
    add_text(0, 0, "MOISTURE:")
    add_text(0, 1, (moisture))
    add_text(0, 2, "Plant Status:")
    add_text(0, 3, "Dry :(")
if OLEDcounter == 1:
    add_text(0, 0, "MOISTURE:")
    add_text(0, 1, moisture)
    add_text(0, 2, "Plant Status:")
    add_text(0, 3, "Happy :)")

while True:
    moisture = pin1.read_analog()
    update_oled_status()
    if moisture >= 700:
        OLEDcounter = 0
        update_oled_status()
    if moisture <= 699:
        OLEDcounter = 1
        update_oled_status()
```

Comment: (1) Please share your complete error, instead of indicating the line number, (2) share a snip code with sample data to test your code.